# Как изменить иконку исполняемого файла

Tags: java, javafx

На днях столкнулся с такой проблемой: создал артефакт в IntellijIdea 2016. программа мне выдала инсталятор и .exe файл уже готовый. Вопрос в следующем, как изменить иконку получившегося исполняемого файла на свою а не на дефолтную? Где можно найти эти настройки артефакта, где можно изменять иконки и существуют ли такие?

Comment: Ну дак, где собираете и разворачиваете `exe` там и делаете иконку, потенциально `java` никакого отношения не имеет к `exe`. - Это делает сторонний софт.

Answer (score 0):

Проставить свою кастомную иконку можно передам нужную иконку основному `stage` вашего приложения.

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("path/to/icon"));
```

Comment: это изменение иконки внутри программы, а мне нужно изменить иконку самого exe